# Entity framework awful join

Tags: entity-framework, linq

```
await ctx.TBL_MST_TRANSPORT_CONFIG
                            .GroupJoin(ctx.TBL_MST_PROVINCE,
                                a=> a.from_province,
                                b=> b.province_code,
                                (a, b)=> new { a, b })
                            .SelectMany(x => x.b.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                                (aa, bb) => new { aa, bb })
                            .GroupJoin(ctx.TBL_MST_PROVINCE,
                                c=> c.aa.a.to_province,
                                d=> d.province_code,
                                (c, d)=> new { c, d })
                            .SelectMany(x => x.d.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                                (cc, dd) => new { cc, dd })
                            .Where(x =>  x.cc.c.aa.a.from_province == province &&
                                x.cc.c.aa.a.flag == true)
                                .Select(x =>  new TransportDTO
                                {
                                    departure = x.cc.c.aa.a.departure,
                                    destination = x.cc.c.aa.a.destination,
                                    from_province = x.cc.c.aa.a.from_province + "-" + x.cc.d.FirstOrDefault().province_desc,
                                    service_provider = x.cc.c.aa.a.service_provider,
                                    to_province = x.cc.c.aa.a.to_province + "-" + x.dd.province_desc,
                                    transport_leave_dc = x.cc.c.aa.a.transport_leave_dc,
                                    transport_no = x.cc.c.aa.a.transport_no,
                                    transport_type = x.cc.c.aa.a.transport_type,
                                })
```

anywhere to reduce this `x.cc.c.aa.a`, it look awfully bad, is there any better way to do it? I forsee it will for each join will just increase the size of the finding

it also generate awful sql

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Project5].[departure] AS [departure], 
    [Project5].[destination] AS [destination], 
    [Project5].[from_province] + N''-'' + CASE WHEN ([Project5].[C1] IS NULL) THEN N'''' ELSE [Project5].[C2] END AS [C2], 
    [Project5].[service_provider] AS [service_provider], 
    [Project5].[to_province] + N''-'' + CASE WHEN ([Project5].[province_desc] IS NULL) THEN N'''' ELSE [Project5].[province_desc] END AS [C3], 
    [Project5].[transport_leave_dc] AS [transport_leave_dc], 
    [Project5].[transport_no] AS [transport_no], 
    [Project5].[transport_type] AS [transport_type]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project3].[transport_type] AS [transport_type], 
        [Project3].[from_province] AS [from_province], 
        [Project3].[to_province] AS [to_province], 
        [Project3].[service_provider] AS [service_provider], 
        [Project3].[transport_no] AS [transport_no], 
        [Project3].[transport_leave_dc] AS [transport_leave_dc], 
        [Project3].[departure] AS [departure], 
        [Project3].[destination] AS [destination], 
        [Project3].[province_desc] AS [province_desc], 
        [Project3].[C1] AS [C1], 
        (SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Extent5].[province_desc] AS [province_desc]
            FROM [dbo].[TBL_MST_PROVINCE] AS [Extent5]
            WHERE [Project3].[to_province] = [Extent5].[province_code]) AS [C2]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project2].[transport_type] AS [transport_type], 
            [Project2].[from_province] AS [from_province], 
            [Project2].[to_province] AS [to_province], 
            [Project2].[service_provider] AS [service_provider], 
            [Project2].[transport_no] AS [transport_no], 
            [Project2].[transport_leave_dc] AS [transport_leave_dc], 
            [Project2].[departure] AS [departure], 
            [Project2].[destination] AS [destination], 
            [Project2].[province_desc] AS [province_desc], 
            [Project2].[C1] AS [C1]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Filter1].[transport_type] AS [transport_type], 
                [Filter1].[from_province] AS [from_province], 
                [Filter1].[to_province] AS [to_province], 
                [Filter1].[service_provider] AS [service_provider], 
                [Filter1].[transport_no] AS [transport_no], 
                [Filter1].[transport_leave_dc] AS [transport_leave_dc], 
                [Filter1].[departure] AS [departure], 
                [Filter1].[destination] AS [destination], 
                [Extent3].[province_desc] AS [province_desc], 
                (SELECT TOP (1) 
                    [Extent4].[province_desc] AS [province_desc]
                    FROM [dbo].[TBL_MST_PROVINCE] AS [Extent4]
                    WHERE [Filter1].[to_province] = [Extent4].[province_code]) AS [C1]
                FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[transport_type] AS [transport_type], [Extent1].[from_province] AS [from_province], [Extent1].[to_province] AS [to_province], [Extent1].[service_provider] AS [service_provider], [Extent1].[transport_no] AS [transport_no], [Extent1].[transport_leave_dc] AS [transport_leave_dc], [Extent1].[departure] AS [departure], [Extent1].[destination] AS [destination]
                    FROM  [dbo].[TBL_MST_TRANSPORT_CONFIG] AS [Extent1]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TBL_MST_PROVINCE] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[from_province] = [Extent2].[province_code]
                    WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[flag] ) AS [Filter1]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TBL_MST_PROVINCE] AS [Extent3] ON [Filter1].[to_province] = [Extent3].[province_code]
                WHERE [Filter1].[from_province] = @p__linq__0
            )  AS [Project2]
        )  AS [Project3]
    )  AS [Project5]',N'@p__linq__0 varchar(8000)',@p__linq__0='01'
```

am i doing correct?

ever i format it like this, it still generate very bad query in sql

```
await ctx.TBL_MST_TRANSPORT_CONFIG
                            .GroupJoin(ctx.TBL_MST_PROVINCE,
                                a=> a.from_province,
                                b=> b.province_code,
                                (a, b)=> new { a, b = b.DefaultIfEmpty() })
                            .GroupJoin(ctx.TBL_MST_PROVINCE,
                                c=> c.a.to_province,
                                d=> d.province_code,
                                (c, d)=> new { c, d = d.DefaultIfEmpty() })
                            .Where(x =>  x.c.a.from_province == province &&
                                x.c.a.flag == true)
```

Comment: EF6 has worst SQL generator ever. So do not expect miracle. Also why you have not written this query in LINQ Query Syntax?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, i try to implement the standard across the application, since I been using EF linq, so I thought I can achieve the same, but seem like my assumption is wrong

Comment: And you are wrong. Use LINQ Query syntax when it is needed - a lot. of joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing multiple (left) joins in lambda syntax in LINQ, it really helps if you:

1. Name your lambda variables meaningful names: I prefer to name anonymous types by their member names concatenated (in this case, with `_` due to the repeated join). I suffix `GroupJoin` results with `j` and `GroupBy` results with `g`.
2. Flatten your anonymous types as you go, including only the needed members as well.

If you do this, you may even discover you have an inconsistency in your query: why do you use the left join (`GroupJoin`/`SelectMany`) to flatten the `from_province` and then use `FirstOrDefault` on the join result anyway? You don't need to do both. Below, I kept the left join syntax:

```
var ans = await ctx.TBL_MST_TRANSPORT_CONFIG
                        .GroupJoin(ctx.TBL_MST_PROVINCE,
                            tc => tc.from_province,
                            pr => pr.province_code,
                            (tc, frprj)=> new { tc, frprj })
                        .SelectMany(tc_frprj => tc_frprj.frprj.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                            (tc_frprj, frpr) => new { tc_frprj.tc, frpr })
                        .GroupJoin(ctx.TBL_MST_PROVINCE,
                            tc_frpr => tc_frpr.tc.to_province,
                            topr => topr.province_code,
                            (tc_frpr, toprj)=> new { tc_frpr.tc, tc_frpr.frpr, toprj })
                        .SelectMany(tc_frpr_toprj => tc_frpr_toprj.toprj.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                            (tc_frpr_toprj, topr) => new { tc_frpr_toprj.tc, tc_frpr_toprj.frpr, topr })
                        .Where(tc_frpr_topr =>  tc_frpr_topr.tc.from_province == province &&
                            tc_frpr_topr.tc.flag)
                        .Select(tc_frpr_topr => new TransportDTO {
                            departure = tc_frpr_topr.tc.departure,
                            destination = tc_frpr_topr.tc.destination,
                            from_province = tc_frpr_topr.tc.from_province + "-" + tc_frpr_topr.frpr.province_desc,
                            service_provider = tc_frpr_topr.tc.service_provider,
                            to_province = tc_frpr_topr.tc.to_province + "-" + tc_frpr_topr.topr.province_desc,
                            transport_leave_dc = tc_frpr_topr.tc.transport_leave_dc,
                            transport_no = tc_frpr_topr.tc.transport_no,
                            transport_type = tc_frpr_topr.tc.transport_type,
                        });
```

NOTE: Since you only use `frpr.province_desc` and `trpr.province_desc` in the final result, you could change the `SelectMany` to just forward those fields (e.g. `frprd = frpr.provice_desc`) and change the lambda names (e.g. `tc_frprd`) and not the entire `frpr` object. It should make no difference to the final translated SQL query.

PS Don't compare booleans against `true` or `false`.

Comment: still, it generated awful sql query, I will take @Svyatoslav Danyliv advice to use linq to sql in future

Comment: @Se0ng11 Changing to query syntax doesn't imply LINQ to SQL - you are still using LINQ to EF if you are querying EF contexts. Also query syntax is transformed by the compiler into lambda syntax, so the eventual translation to SQL will be the same as well.

Answer (score 1):

That's why LINQ Query syntax is better when you have a lot of joins.

```cs
var query =
    from tc in ctx.TBL_MST_TRANSPORT_CONFIG
    join fp in ctx.TBL_MST_PROVINCE on tc.from_province equals fp.province_code into fpj
    from fp in fpj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join tp in ctx.TBL_MST_PROVINCE on tc.to_province equals tp.province_code into tpj
    from tp in tpj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where tc.from_province == province && tc.flag == true
    select new TransportDTO
    {
        departure = tc.departure,
        destination = tc.destination,
        from_province = tc.from_province + "-" + fp.province_desc,
        service_provider = tc.service_provider,
        to_province = tc.to_province + "-" + tp.province_desc,
        transport_leave_dc = tc.transport_leave_dc,
        transport_no = tc.transport_no,
        transport_type = tc.transport_type,
    }
```

It does not guarantee better SQL, but maintenance and readability improved a lot.

Comment: yes, can see that LINQ Query is way better than the EF :(